# DNS problem: no A record

Tags: debian, dns, bind

Ten days ago, i installed a debian 9 stretch, at Kimsufi by OVH. i receive an email from support wich contains a problem with A record, my server is ns.xzave.net, and there is no record A on my server

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/ns.xzave.net i don't have a A record

dig from google toolbox  on"creation-site-pro.fr"

https://www.toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/

```
id 5158
opcode QUERY
rcode SERVFAIL
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
creation-site-pro.fr. IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

service bind9 status :

```
bind9.service - BIND Domain Name Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bind9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-06-09 15:48:15 UTC; 6min ago
     Docs: man:named(8)
 Main PID: 665 (named)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bind9.service
           └─665 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind

Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: managed-keys-zone: journal file is out of date: removing journal file
Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 415
Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: zone creation-site-pro.fr/IN: loaded serial 2019052810
Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: all zones loaded
Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: running
Jun 09 15:48:18 ns named[665]: zone creation-site-pro.fr/IN: sending notifies (serial 2019052810)
```

file named.conf   :

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

file named.conf.local

```
zone "creation-site-pro.fr" {
        type master;
        allow-transfer {213.186.33.199;};
        file "/etc/bind/pri.creation-site-pro.fr";
        allow-query{any;};
        notify yes;
};
```

file named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        // forwarders {
        //      0.0.0.0;
        // };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation auto;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

hostname:

```
ns
```

hostname -f

```
ns.xzave.net
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

According to the `fr.` zone, `creation-site-pro.fr` has two nameservers

```
creation-site-pro.fr.   172800  IN  NS  ns.xzave.net.
creation-site-pro.fr.   172800  IN  NS  ns.kimsufi.com.
```

Of these two, `ns.xzave.net.` doesn't exist (`xzave.net.` isn't even a registered domain) and `ns.kimsufi.com.` seems to be refusing queries.

While your Debian server might be configured correctly to answer queries on the zone, it isn't accessible as it's hostname `ns.xzave.net.` doesn't point to it.

You might want to consider either using the name service supplied by the registrar (if they provide one) or make sure the server has a proper FQDN which points to it. You will also need to sort out the other server that's refusing queries.